# WPF validate on single datagrid column

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, xaml, datagrid

I have written a ValidationRule in the code-behind, but it I only want it to trigger when editing/adding a value in a certain column. So when I change another value in another column, the validation should not trigger. How am I able to do this?

I now have the ValidationRule assigned to the datagrid like this:

```
<DataGrid.RowValidationRules>
    <local:ValidationRule ValidationStep="UpdatedValue"/>
</DataGrid.RowValidationRules>
```

Comment: You can define an edit and display template for a column and put the validation rule in the edit template. How code behind comes into this I don't really follow.

Comment: The ValidationRule is defined in the code behind.

Comment: Validationrules are always defined in code. Is this one somehow different?  Don't attach it to the row if you need it to be on one field. They apply to bindings. Apply it to the binding on your one field in the edit template for that field as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed it by adding it to the datagridtextcolumn like this:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="FOO">
    <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
        <Binding Path="foo" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <local:ValidationRule/>
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
     </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```